# Какая разница между «слабеть» и «ослабевать»?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, глаголы

Зачем одному «ослабеть» два несовершенных вида?

Answer (score 5):

Второй вариант, образованный от *совершенной* формы глагола (ослабеть), позволяет выразить достижение некоторой *меры* или *порога* слабости, например:

> По мере удаления поршня от магнита их взаимное притяжение **слабеет**,
> а на расстоянии 10 см оно **ослабевает** настолько, что поршень падает
> под действием силы тяжести.
>
> При отказе от пищи человек **слабеет**, причём на 5-й день он
> **ослабевает** настолько, что начинает падать в обморок.

Comment: но в принципе **слабеет** и **ослабевает** (и **слабнет** тоже) в этих предложениях взаимозаменимы, преимущество второго в том, что он позволяет избежать тавтологии

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказала, что "**ослабевать**" выражает еще большую постепенность действия, чем "**слабеть**". Но в целом они синонимичны и взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 1):

Cуществует ещё глагол **«(о)слабнуть»**.

На глазок я бы сказал, что **«(о)слабеть»** применяется по отношению к одушевлённым предметам, а **«ослабевать»** и **«(о)слабнуть»** - к неодушевлённым. Это не железное правило, но такова, мне кажется, тенденция.